# Angular Material Radio Button Wrap Text

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How to wrap the text of Angular Material Radio Button?

See repo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-wrap-text

Tried and didn't work (according to https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10954):

```
white-space: normal;
```

What worked is using the `<span></span>` technique. But why this works but not the `white-space: normal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 points to solving this.

1) Consider [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) For that reason I have added `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your Component decorator. If you don't specify `ViewEncapsulation.None` then all your styles are encapsulated and they don't bleed out so they can't affect your child radio component. If you don't want to do that then apply CSS rule in "general" stylesheet.

2) After that it is important to have right CSS selector which will overwrite original. You could use something general like `.example-radio-button > *` and then define `white-space` in conjunction with `!important` or be more specific with the selector like `.example-radio-button .mat-radio-label` and then you don't need `!important`

Working example can be found here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-wrap-text-paghtt

Answer (score 3):

Put the following code in the style.scss file:

```
.mat-radio-label-content {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This variant works:

```
::ng-deep div.mat-radio-label-content {
  white-space: normal;
}
```